# How do we send a payload in webhook based alert notification in grafana?

Tags: alert, webhooks, nagios, grafana, payload

I am trying to configure webhook notifications for alerts on grafana. I am unable to understand how to send the payload. There is no option to add the payload while we are adding a webhook notification channel. Do we have to add it in the URL itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's currently not possible. But we have an issue for it https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6956